# How to customize the table names which are used with a EDMX (Model First) Entity Framework 4.1?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am currently having a inheritance model in my Model First Entity Framework 4.1 (June 2011 CTP) model.

I have a base type 'BusinessEntity' from which 'Organization' inherits.

Is it possible to specify the table (TPT structure) which is used to persist the Organization data?

Right now, it is defaulting to BusinessEntities_Organization whereas I want 'Organizations'

Comment: Didn't know this was such a brain teaser!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to annotate your class "Organization" like below to tell EF which table to use:

```
[Table("Organizations")]
public class Organization {...}
```

Comment: Since I am using a model first approach and the code is actually autogenerated, I don't this would apply.